# References of ALL Properties MsBuild

Tags: deployment, scripting, msbuild, properties, projects-and-solutions

Where is a complete reference of ALL MsBuild properties ?? Like this

$(OutDir)

$(OutputPath)

$(TargetName)

$(TargetExt)

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx)

1. [Common MSBuild Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)
2. [MSBuild Reserved Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx)

It sounds like there can be more project-type-specific properties; which project types are you dealing with?

Comment: a .net project, Class Library with little modifications.

Comment: Do you know if there is a similar reference for the actions/events that occur during the build/publish of an application. Regularly you come across examples where they say you need to extend for instance the 'CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn' property, but I've yet to see some list of what properties are used in a typical (web) application.

Comment: @Robba No, sorry. You can find them all in Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets, which is under C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\Web or similar, and there are some comments in there. That's better than nothing, but I'd hope for better documentation.

Comment: Ah, at least that's something. I'll have a look (and probably cry myself to sleep in despair... again) Thanks